# Searching a tuple for a matching pair

Tags: haskell

> [(3,9),(4,16),(5,25)] 4 = 16

I was using `map (\(x,y ) -> x) [(3,9),(4,16),(5,25)]` to get the fst of every element, and then was going to filter it for the match--but I'm having errors just making the first piece work:

```
findTup :: Rel -> Int -> Int
findTup rs a = map (\(x,y ) -> x) rs
```

> - Couldn't match expected type 'Int' with actual type '[Int]'
> - In the expression: map (\ (x, y) -> x) rs

Is there any way to make map work on the tuple with `Int -> Int`?

Comment: You might want `lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b`.

Comment: Currently, you are only getting the `[Int]` value returned by `map`, but you already stated that `findTup` would return an `Int`, not a `[Int]`.

Comment: `\(x,y) -> x` is already defined as `fst`.

Comment: You may find it interesting to delete the type signature for `findTup` and see what happens. If it compiles, what type is inferred? If it doesn't compile, how does the error change? Do you find yourself surprised by the outcome?

Comment: First things first, before checking the tuples have you decided what would be the answer if you fail to find a match?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with what you have for `findTup`. If we put your function into ghci and ask it for the type we get

```
ghci> findTup rs a = map (\(x,y) -> x) rs
ghci> :t findTup
findTup :: [(b1, b2)] -> p -> [b1]
```

This tells us that your function returns a list of items that have some type `b1`, which makes sense given that the type signature of map is `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. Another function that applies a given function to every element of a list which is more useful to us here is `filter`. Filter has a type signature of `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`.

So lets try replacing the `map` in your code with `filter` which gives `findTup rs a = filter (\(x, y) -> x) rs`. Now if we check the type we find that it is `findTup :: [(Bool, b)] -> p -> [(Bool, b)]`. There's still a few problems with this function. For starters, `(\(x, y) -> x)` is constraining our input to have a boolean in the first item of the tuple, but that isn't what we want. We need to rewrite the filtering function so that it actually performs our search. `(\(x, y) -> x == a)` is what we actually want. This will cause filter to return only the elements that match the one we are searching for. Now we can see that `findTup :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> a -> [(a, b)]`.

Unfortunately this still returns a list, and we only want a single item. We can use the `head` function to get only the first item that matches, so `findTup rs a = head $ filter (\(x, y) -> x == a) rs`. Ghci tells us that the signature for this function is `findTup :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> a -> (a, b)` which is so close to what we want. The only thing left is to get just the second value from the tuple, which we can do with the function `snd`.

So our final code will be `findTup rs a = snd . head $ filter (\(x, y) -> x == a) rs`. A quick check in ghci shows `findTup :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> a -> b`. Substituting `Int` in for the type variables we find `findTup :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your declared type doesn't match your partial implementation. You could simply change the type until you do the filtering:

```
findTup :: Rel -> Int -> [Int]
findTup rs a = map (\(x,y) -> x) rs
```

or add the filtering. To do that, explicit recursion and pattern matching would be simpler than using `map`:

```
findTup :: Rel -> Int -> Int
-- findTup [] a = ...   -- Omitted to reflect the assumption of success
findTup ((k, v):rs) a = if k == a then v else findTup rs a
```

---

However, there's no need to reinvent the wheel:

```
import Data.Maybe

findTup :: Rel -> Int -> Int
findTup rs a = fromJust (lookup a rs)
```

or, since you probably shouldn't assume the lookup will succeed,

```
findTup :: Rel -> Int -> Maybe Int
findTup = flip lookup
```